# How do you display a browseable list of images obtained from an RSS feed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, xcode, rss

I have a requirement to grab images from an rss feed and display these images in much the same way as browsing your picture library and I really dont know where to start first.

I can get tutorials on the rss reader but I really dont know the component to use to allow the user to "swish" through the images on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a an open source grid view called [AQGridView](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

That will help you in laying out the images in a grid like the photo apps "Camera Roll".

As for swiping between images, you should look into using a `UIScrollView`.

The [Three20](http://three20.info) library has a photo view controller, but it's cumbersome and difficult to set up if you don't know the three20 library very well.

Comment: IN the end I actually created a map of rectangle and used UIWebImageView to display each image at the particular location. I used the UIscrollView to scroll throw each frame so each page in the scroll view contained n rectangles at the positions required